# How can I automatically organize files within a folder based on the name?

Tags: windows, windows-10, sorting

I have a folder with over 4,000 PDF files that my company used to use as a loading dock to upload into our CRM as they were scanned in. We are now switching software and this folder is all that will remain of our files that we want to keep from past jobs. Each file is in this format:

```
companyname - proof.pdf
companyname - notes.pdf
companyname two - proof.pdf
companyname two - vendor file.pdf
```

I am now tasked with creating a folder for each "companyname" and sorting all files we have from that company into its own folder. Which isn't hard, but time consuming. Does anyone know of a way I could run a script or something to automatically create a folder for "companyname" and move each file with that matching name into said folder? Preferably something that could determine what the "companyname" is on its own, because otherwise I'll have to enter in hundreds of different companies and if that's the only way I would rather just do it manually. Thank you in advance!

[Here is a photo example of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGJw8.jpg)

Comment: This could easily be done with C# and/or PowerShell.  Loop through each file in the folder, output the list of files into a text file, use string functions to extract all text before the '-' and only create a folder on the first folder in theory.  We will be unable to write the script for you.  Use File operations to copy the files to the folder as they are created.

Comment: Good to know, I will try to do this. Thank you so much!